# 1 to many relationships flipped

Tags: ms-access

Hi I am trying to create a simple 1 to many relationship from the FolioID of tblGeneralInformation to the FolioID of tblFolio. However when I try to drag from tblGeneralInformation to tblFolio, the tables are flipped and I cannot fix it. The relationship thus is reversed as shown in the picture below. Any idea why this is happening?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you drag from tblFolio to tblGeneralInformation?

Comment: Same thing as here

Comment: Wait, I just took another look at picture. Relationship looks right to me.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no issue.